# Gherkin table - remove repetition

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumberjs, cucumber-java

I have a cucumber gherkin feature file shown below:

```
Feature: Log in

  Scenario Outline: Successful log-in
     Given i enter <username>
     Given and password <password>
     Then I log in

     Examples:
       | username | password |
       | hello | sorry |
       | hello | hello |
       | hello | goodbye |
       | admin | sorry |
       | admin | hello |
       | admin | goodbye |
```

as you can see above in the username and password table, there is a lot of  repetition. how can i remove this repetition?

for example, i could create two features like

(1)

```
Feature: Log in

  Scenario Outline: Successful log-in
     Given i enter hello
     Given and password <password>
     Then I log in

     Examples:
       | password |
       | sorry |
       | hello |
       | goodbye |
```

(2)

```
Feature: Log in

  Scenario Outline: Successful log-in
     Given i enter admin
     Given and password <password>
     Then I log in

     Examples:
       | password |
       | sorry |
       | hello |
       | goodbye |
```

but there is still repetion in here.

is there some other way to remove this repetion. i would like something like:

```
Feature: Log in

  Scenario Outline: Successful log-in
     Given i enter <username>
       | hello |
       | admin |
     Given and password <password>
       | sorry |
       | hello |
       | goodbye |
     Then I log in
```

But i am not sure if the above kinda thing is possible...

PLease help me...

I have ommitted step definitions here since they are easy to do.

Comment: Is this a part of a real scenario? If so, how is it possible for one user to have so many passwords? Are they all valid logins, as in the scenario description it is written successful login.

Comment: No.. it is made up for the sake of an example....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. There isn't a way to multiply out the examples in the `Examples` table.

However, there is an alternative that aids readability and increases the understanding of the tests from the business (which is what you really want to do with BDD-style tests).

```
Background:
  Given I am on the login page

Scenario Outline: Logging in with valid passwords
  When I attempt to log in as <user_type> with a valid password
  Then I should see the <page> page

 Examples:
    | user_type | page            |
    | a user    | home            |
    | an admin  | admin dashboard |

Scenario Outline: Logging in with invalid passwords
  When I attempt to log in as <user_type> with an invalid password
  Then I should see the password validation

 Examples:
   | user_type |
   | a user    |
   | an admin  |
```

`Background`'s can take away the repetition of the set up steps (assuming they are the same throughout all the scenarios within a feature) and if you group each scenario outline by what it is attempting to achieve, you should have more readability overall, with the intent of the tests clearly expressed.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't have given a better answer than @kyle-fairns.

But for completeness, as your scenario might be oversimplified (which may hide your true intentions).

- Use [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#tagged-hooks) or environment/world variables to run the exact same scenario with different parameters.
- Generate your pairwise testing tables, something like described here: http://blog.josephwilk.net/ruby/pairwise-testing-with-cucumber.html

Answer (score 0):

I opened issue for it https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/1105 but it was closed :(

Answer (score 0):

Using the bitloops-gherkin package you are able to pull data from a Google Sheet so you could easily check if your test data are distinct there

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitloops-gherkin